# How to create a paginated report of multi-paged subreports with Power BI?

Tags: fonts, powerbi, powerbi-paginated-reports

I want to create a master report that consists of multiple 5-page reports for each sales region (say 10 regions). I am creating a parameter to filter the results based on the region. Every example I found for Power BI paginated report was based on 1-page reports. I wanted to check if it is possible to create my master reports of multi-paged subreports with Power BI paginated report.

One more piece of information to add here is that each of my subreports includes a combination of tables and graphs and the number of rows in some tables may vary for each regional report (pushing some rows to the next page). It is also required to conditionally change the font color for certain rows in the table. Please let me know if these features can be applied too.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You may want to check Power BI paginated report
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/paginated-reports/paginated-reports-quickstart-aw